# How to get Number of levels in sub_of using sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table like this,

```
|id | Name   |sub_of|
|1  |Level 1A|  0   |
|2  |Level 1B|  0   |
|3  |Level 1C|  0   |
|4  |Level 1D|  0   |
|5  |Level 2A|  1   |
|6  |Level 2B|  2   |
|7  |Level 2C|  3   |
|8  |Level 3C|  7   |
|9  |Level 4C|  8   |
|10 |Level 5C|  9   |
|11 |Level 3B|  6   |
```

I this case

- A have 2 levels
- B have 3 levels
- c have 5 levels
- d have 1 levels

Sub_of is id of the previous level. Name does not contain sub_of name(ie A does not contains all level of A).

I need Maximum level of the sub_of. Please give some ideas.

Comment: Provide output results sample, as to how it should look like?

Comment: Just i need which have maximum number of row and their count.That means sub_of value 0 is our master row and other rows are sub of master rows.

Comment: is there a field that identifies for example all rows of level A?

Comment: no field that identifies.from end of the row data we find previous level by sub_of.That means 10th row identify 9th,9th row identify 8th,8th row identify 7th,7th row identify 3rd.The 3rd row sub_of is 0 end.

Comment: 'Level 1A' is the real name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a unique identifier for each level (A, B, C, ...)

Using a recursive cte query I've used the first id where sub_of = 0 as a unique identifier:

```
;WITH tree AS
(
    SELECT c1.id, c1.name, c1.sub_of, [id_level] = c1.id, [level] = 1
    FROM dbo.[btree2] c1
    WHERE c1.sub_of = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c2.id, c2.name, c2.sub_of, [id_level] = tree.[id_level], [level] = tree.[level] + 1
    FROM dbo.[btree2] c2 INNER JOIN tree ON c2.sub_of = tree.id
)
SELECT t1.id, t1.sub_of, t1.name, t1.id_level, t1.level
FROM tree t1
     INNER JOIN (SELECT id_level, MAX(level) AS level FROM tree GROUP BY id_level) t2
     ON t1.id_level = t2.id_level AND t1.level = t2.level
ORDER BY id_level, level
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
;
```

Then simply get MAX(level) for each group.

```
+----+--------+----------+----------+-------+
| id | sub_of | name     | id_level | level |
+----+--------+----------+----------+-------+
| 5  |    1   | Level 2A |     1    |   2   |
| 11 |    6   | Level 3B |     2    |   3   |
| 10 |    9   | Level 5C |     3    |   5   |
| 4  |    0   | Level 1D |     4    |   1   |
+----+--------+----------+----------+-------+
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/KIEY97438

Answer (score 2):

Recursive cte is your friend...

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T as TABLE
(
    id int,
    Name varchar(10), 
    sub_of int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1  ,'Level 1A',0),
(2  ,'Level 1B',0),
(3  ,'Level 1C',0),
(4  ,'Level 1D',0),
(5  ,'Level 2A',1),
(6  ,'Level 2B',2),
(7  ,'Level 2C',3),
(8  ,'Level 3C',7),
(9  ,'Level 4C',8),
(10 ,'Level 5C',9),
(11 ,'Level 3B',6)
```

The cte:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT id, Name, Sub_Of, 0 As Level
    FROM @T
    WHERE Sub_Of = 0

    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, t.Name, t.Sub_Of, Level + 1 
    FROM @T as t
    INNER JOIN CTE ON t.Sub_Of = CTE.id  
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY Level DESC
```

Results:

```
id  Name        Sub_Of  Level
10  Level 5C    9       4
9   Level 4C    8       3
11  Level 3B    6       2
8   Level 3C    7       2
7   Level 2C    3       1
6   Level 2B    2       1
5   Level 2A    1       1
1   Level 1A    0       0
2   Level 1B    0       0
3   Level 1C    0       0
4   Level 1D    0       0
```

Comment: Sure my future question should have these steps.Thank You.

Comment: Great. Glad I could help.